# Buying bitcoin from anonymous person on legal websites like localbitcoins.com

Tags: transactions

I want to buy bitcoin from some sites like localbitcoins.com ,because I do not know who the seller is I worry that Seller might have earned the bitcoins through illegal ways like drug dealing or stealing other people money and I worry that it might make a problem for me in the future if I but those bitcoins for instance the government or police might arrest me and ask me questions that why I have bought bitcoins from criminals this stops me from buying bitcoin on localbitcoins .Do you think it is something that I should worry about it ?

Comment: Unless you are buying in excess of $50,000 I would not worry about it, and you would probably find it hard to buy that much on localbitcoins. The $ notes you have in your pocket more than likely have trace amounts of actual drugs on them from previous owner using them http://www.snopes.com/business/money/cocaine.asp